# How can I edit a range of text between 2 symbols? awk, sed, regex

Tags: bash, sed, regex, awk

Using the "*" symbol, (doesn't have to be that one, any special character will do in order to indicate), how can I edit the text from this:

```
*berry
straw
rasp
blue
boysen
*
blahblah
blahblah
blahblah
*berry
straw
blue
*
blah
*table
vege
pingpong
*
```

To this:

```
strawberry
raspberry
blueberry
boysenberry
blahblah
blahblah
blahblah
strawberry
blueberry
blah
vegetable
pingpongtable
```

Every character after the first matching asterisk will be placed on every line until the 2nd asterisk match is found.

Any leads on how I can go about this? (sed or awk would be preferred, but if you can think of another way, please shoot me your code!)

I know how to remove all lines containing an asterisk, it's just the character placement part I can't think of

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This `awk` code could be enough:

```
awk -F'*' 'NF == 2 {label = $2; next} {$0 = $0 label} 1'
```

To break it down:

- Use `*` as the field separator. This way, we can simply examine the number of fields  (`NF`) to determine if the beginning or end of a block is reached.
- When there are two fields, we save the second field in `label` and continue to the next line.
- From then, we append that `label` to the current line, and then print. If the label is empty, we are outside a block and there's no effect. If not, we get the required output.

Answer (score 8):

In `sed`, you could copy the "special" line into hold space before deleting it

```
sed -e '/^\*/{h;d;}'
```

and then append the hold space to each succeeding pattern space, replacing the resulting newline and marker character

```
    -e '{G;s/\n\*//;}'
```

Testing it with your data,

```
$ sed -e '/^\*/{h;d;}' -e '{G;s/\n\*//;}' file
strawberry
raspberry
blueberry
boysenberry
blahblah
blahblah
blahblah
strawberry
blueberry
blah
vegetable
pingpongtable
```

Note: this doesn't stop when it encounters the second asterisk; it does exactly the same, but it's appending `*` followed by nothing - until it matches the next `*sometext`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Perl way:

```
$ perl -lne '/^\*(.*)/ || print "$_$1"' file
strawberry
raspberry
blueberry
boysenberry
blahblah
blahblah
blahblah
strawberry
blueberry
blah
vegetable
pingpongtable
```

#### Explanation

The `-n` will cause Perl to read each line of the input file, saving it in the special variable `$_`, the `-l` will cause it to i) strip trailing newlines (`\n`) from each line and ii) add a newline to each call of `print`. The `-e` is the script that is applied to each line.

- `/^\*(.*)/` : match lines that start with an asterisk and save everything after the asterisk as `$1` (that's what the parentheses do).
- `|| print "$_$1"'` : the `||` is a logical `OR`. Therefore, the `print` will only be executed if the current line did not start with an asterisk. If so, we print the current line (`$_`) along with whatever is currently saved as `$1` (the pattern following the asterisk).

---

As usual, there are many ways of doing this. A silly and inefficient one, but one which highlights the string manipulation capabilities of the shell, is:

```
$ while read line; do 
    [[ $line =~ ^\* ]] && pat="${line#\*}" || printf "%s%s\n" "$line" "$pat"; 
  done < file
strawberry
raspberry
blueberry
boysenberry
blahblah
blahblah
blahblah
strawberry
blueberry
blah
vegetable
pingpongtable
```

#### Explanation

- `while read line; do ... ; done < file` : this is a classic `while` loop which will read each line of the input file `file` and save it as `$line`.
- `[[ $line =~ ^\* ]] && pat="${line#\*}"` : if the line starts with an `*`, remove everything after that (that's what the `${line#\*}` does, for more details, see [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)) and save it as `$pat`.
  *`|| printf "%s%s\n" "$line" "$pat";` : if the previous command failed (so, the line does not start with an asterisk), print the line and the current value of `$pat`.

---

Answer (score 3):

Through my favorite Python...

```
with open('/path/to/the/file') as f:
    counter = False
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('*') and not counter:
            m = line.strip().lstrip('*')
            counter = True
        elif line.startswith('*') and counter:
            counter = False    
        elif counter:
            if not line.startswith('*'):
                print(line.strip() + m)
        else:
            print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 3):

Came here late. Here is another `python` approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for lines in f.read().split('*'):
        entries = lines.rstrip().split('\n')
        for i in range(1, len(entries)):
            print entries[i] + entries[0]
```